# Running a expect script within eclipse shell

Tags: eclipse, bash, console, eclipse-cdt, expect

I made an expect **e.exp** script file which is called inside two nested bash scripts **b1** and **b12**

As far as I run the **b1** bash script in terminal every thing is Ok and fine so the expect can send the password and all the files are save on the target device.

As soon as I call the script from **eclipse CDT 3.8.0 Indigo**, I can not copy the files since it seems it can not send the **password inside expect script**

### How can I deal with that problem (either in eclipse or bash shell)

I described and simplified the implementation as follows

b1 --calls inside-> b2 --calls inside-> e.exp   (works in terminal but not in eclipse console) 
 :(

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to resolve this?
How are you exactly running the script from Eclipse?

Try adding sleep between the username and password, works most of the times

```
#login process
sleep 10
expect -re "ubuntu login: "
sleep 5
#send user name

send -- "root\r"
sleep 10
expect -exact "root\r\r
Password: "
sleep 10
#send the password
```